# Wagtail - show latest 3 posts but filter the 3 posts when in the latest post selected

Tags: python, django, wagtail

bit hard to explain this one but I will give it my best. I am trying to develop a wagtail website and all is looking fine, but now I have come across a problem. In my side panel to the right I have the latest 3 posts published. This always shows the latest 3 posts which is great for further reading but when I select one of those posts in the side panel, the post that I have selected is still visible in the side panel.

So basically I am looking for some kind of restructuring to my models to say if post selected, in side panel show the next latest post applicable instead.

a visual representation is thus:

[image]

So my code is as follows:

template:

```
<div class="col-2__sm">
        <div class="card">
            
            {% for child in page.get_recent_blogs %}
            <div class="col-1 card__block">
                <div class="card__content news-blocks">
                    <a class="blog__recent-posts" href="{{ child.url }}">
                        
                        <div class="image">
                            {% image child.image fill-850x450-c100  %}
                        </div>
                        <h3>{{ child.title }}</h3>
                        <p>{{ child.introduction|truncatewords:15 }}</p>
                        <span>Read More</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
```

In my model I have this:

```
def get_recent_blogs(self):
    max_count = 3
    return BlogPage.objects.all().order_by(
        '-first_published_at')[:max_count]

# add this to custom context
def get_context(self, request):
    context = super(BlogPage, self).get_context(request)
    context['blogs'] = self.get_recent_blogs()
    return context
```

I have tried searching for this but have got no where. I hope I have explained this so you can understand what I am trying to do. I would be very grateful for any help on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Django's `exclude` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#exclude) to filter out the current page:

```
def get_recent_blogs(self):
    max_count = 3
    return BlogPage.objects.exclude(id=self.id).order_by(
        '-first_published_at')[:max_count]
```